# I really need help installing the Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 Driver!

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, broadcom

I hope someone can help! Well here is a description: I am new to Ubuntu, and just installed it. I am having allot of trouble getting my wifi adapter to work... here is the model: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 
What should i do? And how do i do it? Any good feedback would be immensely liked, Thanks! (I have access to Internet through Ethernet)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](http://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers)

Answer (score 1):

Open a terminal - to do this press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> - and then execute the following commands :

```
sudo apt-get update  
sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source  
sudo reboot
```

After the restart of the operating system you are able to use the BROADCOM wireless adapter.

Comment: Darn, it didn't work ): the option to connect to a wireless network isn't there

Comment: @Ryanlf999 : When you click on the network icon your wireless network name should be shown ... click on it, enter your wireless network password and connect ... or are there no wireless networks offered at all ?